# Unable to show Overlay on Bar graph using Android MP chart library

Tags: android, charts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtcP9.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtcP9.png)As I am developing an application in which I need to show the overlay over the bar charts. I am using the Android MP Chart library for this.But in that library there is no way to show overlay over the bar charts.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

This is what I have achieved the only thing left is the overlay
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EylWz.png)

Comment: Hi siddharth,please add an image to your question so that others can view the issue you are facing and assist you accordingly.Example snippets of what you've already tried to do ignorer to solve your problem will also be very helpful.

Comment: Actually I didn't find anything which will solve my problem .The only thing that I am thinking is to customize the library .Any other workaround is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use another library for example

- https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android
- http://www.android-graphview.org

These libraries I introduced to you have good documentation

Comment: I have tried these libraries but they are not as good as compared to the Android Mp chart library.It is robust library which provides you the great animations also